# Entity Framework Migrations Error : Sequence contains no elements - Timestamp

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I have been create a project in VS2015 with **entity framework 6 - Code First** with

EntityFramework [6.0.0.0]

mysql.data.entity.EF6 [6.8.3.0]

I am try Migrations

> **command**: Add-Migration Initial
>  
>   **error**: Sequence contains no matching element

I've been trying a bunch of things, and get the cause of this

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

this is the sample model-code first

```
using MySql.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TokoBersama.Model
{
    // Code-Based Configuration and Dependency resolution
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class MySqlDatabaseConnection : DbContext
    {


        #region Tabels

        public DbSet<returnpenjualan> ReturnPenjualan { get; set; }         

        #endregion

        #region member Event
        public MySqlDatabaseConnection()
            : base("name=myConnectionString")
        {

        }

        public MySqlDatabaseConnection(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
      : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
        {

        }

        //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        //{
        //    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //
        //    Map entity to table
        //    modelBuilder.Entity<jenis>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        //}

        #endregion

    }

    #region tabels

    public class returnpenjualan
    {
        [Key]
        [StringLength(12)]
        public string frjb { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(12)]
        public string fjb { get; set; }

        //THE CAUSE OF ERROR
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string kepada { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(45)]
        public string alamat { get; set; }


        [StringLength(45)]
        public string ktp { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public double jumlahreturnpenjualan { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(45)]
        public string username { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

**ASK** 
I've search tutorial and the like for using **Timestamp** in DataAnnotation and get the same answer for using "Timestamp", is there something iam missing to use "Timestamp"???

Answer (score 0):

I have been search **"mysql ef6: timestamp"** and using this code for the time being, i don't know this the best solution for my question, is there some another solution, please reply

```
[Column(TypeName = "timestamp")]
public DateTime RowVersion { get; set; }
```